# bulk insert with chinese character

Tags: encoding, utf-8, insert, bulk

I want to bulk insert a csv data file, which contains Chinese characters, to sql server 2012. the original encoding of the csv data file is utf8, and fmt file is generated by bcp tool. the question is that if I convert the encoding of csv data file from utf8 to unicode via notepad(open the data file with notepad, then choose 'save as' and select the 'unicode' format), I can bulk insert the data to database. And if I keep its original encoding, nothing will be inserted to database.

any one knows if there exists any script, such as python or powershell, can automate to convert data file from utf-8 encoding to unicode and keep the Chinese characters without changing.
thanks.

Comment: Note: utf-8 is an encoding of Unicode. Windows notepad erroneously labels "UTF-16 LE" as "Unicode".

Comment: So, you're looking for an automated way to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 LE/Unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a UTF-8 document, possibly with a UTF-8 BOM, to UTF-16-LE using Python:

```
import io
with io.open("my_input_file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as my_input:
    with io.open("my_output_file.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-16-LE") as my_output:
        my_ouput.write( u"\uFEFF" ) # write a UTF BOM
        my_ouput.write( my_input.read() )
```

Comment: Thanks Alastair,  your answer is really useful for me.